# Force study alert at candle close

Tags: alert, pine-script, trading

Small question, I use 3 indicators that I have combined into 1 to send webhook alerts for more simplicity

The problem is that this indicator can often give me 2 signals in a row at the close of a candle. For example in H1 the 1st alert at 3 p.m. and the 2nd at 4 p.m. The order is random, part 1 of the indicator may trigger first, part 2 also.

Only the 1st signal interests me.

The problem is that once the 1st signal is gone, the next one shouldn't be sent as well.

Is there a way to force the 1st alert when the candle closes without checking the box in the alert setting? In fact, it triggers on closing and then deactivates. like that no double alert, I will reactivate it manually (1 or 2 signals per day)

Basically, Alert at the close of the candle but only once.

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: You can do it in your code. Can you hsare your code?